# Application level variable initialization in asp classic

Tags: asp-classic, global.asa

I have legacy ASP classic website. If I dump all the application variables using

```
For Each item In Application.Contents 
    Response.Write item & " = " & Application(item) 
    Response.Write "<br>"      
Next
```

They are all initialized but there is no global.asa file in this application.
Where else the initialization code might be?

Comment: They can be initialized anywhere..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. just add this code in any .asp file and add this file as a top usercontrol in every page so you will get this variable on all pages
2. session is the other option , you can assign all variable in session and can access in any page (I do not recommend this.)